# Building AVL tree in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, tree, avl-tree, b-tree

In self balancing trees like AVL trees, inserting a node take O(log n) where n is the current number of nodes in tree.

Let's suppose I want to build a new AVL tree from scratch with the following values: 1,2,3,4...n Is there a way I can do this in O(n) instead of the traditional way that will take O(n log(n))?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is possible. The idea behind it would be that you have a function that takes a range [x, y], and cuts it into two ranges [x, n), (n, y], makes a node with the value n, and then adds its two children by calling itself with those two ranges as its parameters.

Comment: It turns out it isn't possible according to the link, only for heap

Comment: The link is referring to situations where you are starting with unsorted data. If you know the range is just [1, n], then creating each node is a constant time operation, and linking each node to its parent is a constant time operation, so the whole thing can be done in linear time.